# Which is the correct sentence? (is, is called, called as)

Tags: syntax

Which is the correct sentence?

1. The young cow is calf.
2. The young cow is called calf.
3. The young cow called as calf.

Comment: "A young (baby) cow is called a calf" or  "The baby of a cow is called a calf."

Answer (score 4):

None of your sentences are exactly correct. If you want to make statement about what a young cow is called, try:

> A young cow is called a calf

Comment: But "A young cow is a calf" works as well: "called" is optional.

Comment: Yes, although 'called' makes it clear this is sentence about what a young cow is called

Answer (score 4):

None of these work.

The most natural one is:

> A young/baby cow is (called) a calf.

If you wanna use "The" at the beginning of the sentence, then it would be:

> The baby of a cow is (called) a calf.

Comment: How about this sentence : 1. The young cow is called a calf. is that right ? When we have to use called as in a sentence ?

Comment: @ParthibanMuthiah Every young cow is a calf, so you can not single out a particular cow with the determiner "the", you have to use "a" to express a generality. Moreover, "called as" doesn't exist, unless used in two separate clauses, e.g. "Yesterday I called, as I do every day."